# Implement Runnable's run method, made final by another class in class hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance

I came across a situation like this.

```
public class B{
    public final void run() {
    }
}

public class A extends B implements Runnable{
    //I want to implement Runnable's run method here.
    //But it does not allow as the run method in B is final
}
```

can someone suggest any way I can achieve this.

Comment: call super.run() from A#run

Comment: why you make run() method final in B class ?

Comment: that's the whole point of making methods final - that the subclasses are not able to override them

Comment: @Kartik I know what final method means. I want to implement the Runnable's run method.

Comment: @ddarz4u thanks for updating the question, it's clearer now. As Andy answered, you need to re-think your design - is `A` a `B` or is `A` a `Runnable`

Comment: There is no way to override a final method.  You _must_ either not implement B, change `B` to make the method not final, or use a different method between A and B.  There is no way around that choice.

Answer (score 3):

What is the important thing here: that `A` is a `B` or that `A` is a `Runnable`?

If it's the former (or it's important that it is both a `B` *and* `Runnable`), there is nothing you can do: `B.run` is final, and final means you can't override it.

If it's the latter, use composition:

```
class A implements Runnable {
  final B b; // initialize on field or in constructor.

  @Override public void run() {
    // Your implementation, calling methods/fields on b
    // where you need the behaviour/data of B.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot implement run method in `class A` under the given circumstances as in `class B` which is parent class of `class A` run method has been declared and you can never override `final` methods.

You can either change the name of method in `class B` or you can make the method non-final.